# Why does the font look so weird in terminal?

Tags: command-line, themes, gnome-terminal, fonts

It looks like its weirdly compressed. I don't know how this happened, everything was working fine and then all of a sudden this happened.

[image: Original problem.]

Comment: If you type in the command `reset` in the terminal does it reset the font?

Comment: No it doesn't, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Check your Text Appearance under Edit -> Preferences and try clicking the Reset buttons there.

Comment: What font is it? What is your graphics hardware? Have you tried restarting the machine?

Comment: The font I'm using is Ubuntu Regular, I really like. I tried resetting it under preferences in terminal and that didn't do anything. I have also tried rebooting the machine, that didn't work either. The Graphics hardware is Intel HD Graphics 520 or 530. I don't that there are drivers for Linux for that hardware but I'll check.

Comment: Alright, I feel really dumb. I went to Terminal > Edit > Preferences > There was an option to enable custom font and I enabled it and that fixed it! This is the first time I've been dabbling in Linux, I'm kinda derpy but I think I'm getting the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal > Edit > Preferences > Font. There should be a custom font box that is unchecked. Check the box that says custom font **optional** > select a custom font and font size in terminal.

Preferences in terminal:
[image: Preferences in terminal.]

Custom font enabled:
[image: Custom font enabled.]

Text in terminal fixed and is back to normal:
[image: Text in terminal fixed and is back to normal.]